# Get the value of a element of a class in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table whose code I have pasted below. I want to use jQuery to get the value of the class position (i.e. 0 ) here. I have wrote a jQuery:
`$('.row').children('td').find('.position').val();`

However I am not getting the result as desired!

```
<tr style="background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="node-25275" class="child-of-node-0 row byte_lenght_1 initialized">
<td style="padding-left: 34px;"> abcd </td>
<td style="padding-left: 15px">  loc_type  </td>
<td style="padding-left: 15px">  <input id="main_type">  </td>
<td class="length" style="padding-left: 15px">   1  </td>
<td class="position" style="padding-left: 15px">  0  </td>
<td style="padding-left: 15px">   <input type="hidden" name="row" value="25275"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.row').find('td.position').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td.position').text()
```